# Retrieving Only a Return value from a method that contains System.out.print

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods

How do I retrieve only the return value from a method if there is also a System.out.print in that method. In the following code I will get the return value but every time I call the method it also executes the System.out.print

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = pickAName("bob", "ed", "dan");
    System.out.printf(name);
}

public String pickAName (String...names){            
    System.out.printf("Randomly picking from %d names. %n",names.length);
    Random random = new Random();

    return names[random.nextInt(names.length)];
}
```

Comment: The `System.out` is unrelated to the return value. If you want to return that which is printed, do that. If you don't want something printed, remove that code.

Comment: Put printf in if condition.

Comment: Don't create a `Random` every time - reuse an instance.

Comment: Simplest answer? Pipe the output from the program into `/dev/null`.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to do? "if there is also a System.out.print in that method" is always true, that method call is always in your method.

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question? I mean, the real question. A program does what you tell it to do. When you tell it to print a value each time, then each time you call it ... it prints that value. So, again: what is your real question?

Answer (score 3):

Computers aren't smart - they can only do what you tell them to do. In your case, it's going to hit that call to `printf()` and execute it every time you call this method.

If there is any case in which you *do* want to print that call to `printf()` then you can wrap it with an `if` condition.

If you're never going to need that output, then just remove that line completely.

If you're using that call to `printf()` for debugging purposes, try to get used to using your IDE's debugging tools instead - it will absolutely pay off in the long run. Especially when you start writing much more complex programs, or when you're working with code that you didn't write.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have control of the method, then there is no way to have the System.out.printf() line not execute when you call the pickAName method. By control, I mean you made the pickAName method or can change it.

Comment: True, but there are many ways to stop it printing anything to the console.